# Android: how to create a notification badge for an icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/historyIcon"
    tools:src="@drawable/to_delete"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp" />
```

How can I add a badge image on the top right corner of this `ImageView`? Is it possible to add a secondary image on the same `ImageView`?

Example image:

[image]

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/historyIcon"
            tools:src="@drawable/to_delete"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />

Comment: Here is example https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fLxiig1DyE7nULYpp8nQv3NJIVAQm2I8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/mprofilelogo"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ss"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ccc"
        android:src="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image will be
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple UI, which you can do with help of two separate image view in one Parent Layout.
 i give you one simple idea below, but you can try any other way to doing same:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just change your image source in place of **src** in both image view.
the **1st** image view display main (large) image, 
and the **2nd** one display small image which is on top of right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/historyIcon"
    tools:src="@drawable/to_delete" />
<ImageView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```